# Angular 4, How to bind an input value into the md-radio-group ngModel

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-material

I have this code in my html

```
<md-radio-group #myOption="ngModel" name="myOption" [(ngModel)]="Person.myoption">
    <md-radio-button [value]="'Option 1'">Option 1</md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button [value]="'Option 2'">Option 2</md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button [value]="other" (change)="enableInput($event)">Other</md-radio-button>
    <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput #otherOpt="ngModel" name="otherOpt" [disabled]="another" [(ngModel)]="other" placeholder="Other option..">
    </md-input-container>                    
</md-radio-group>
<div>The option is: {{Person.myoption}}</div>
```

and in my Component.ts

```
enabledInput(e: MdRadioChange){
    if(e.source.checked) {
        this.another=false;
    }
}
```

When I choose first or second option, in the div with {{Person.myoption}} is showed ok, but when I choose the third "Other option", I can't bind it correctly to my div